# "If" non exist in foreach loops - what?

Tags: powershell

When I invoke an `if` comandlet in a `foreach` loop:

```
$spisok = Get-Content "OmConv79_2.txt" -TotalCount 100
foreach ($i in $spisok) {
    #Write-Host $i
    $i -match "^(.*)\t(.+)\t?(.*)?" |
        foreach { $Matches[1] + "----" + $Matches[2] + "----" + $Matches[3] } |
        if ($Matches[1] -eq "^\d\d.\d\d.\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\d") {
            $Matches[0]
        }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
if : The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:7 char:9
+         if ($Matches[1] -eq "^\d\d.\d\d.\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d\d ...
+         ~~
    +         CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (if:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    +         FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image: screenshot]

*"if" is not recognized*? I'm confused. How is that possible?

Comment: You can't pipe to a statement `if`. Use `Where-Object` or its aliases `Where`, `?`.

Comment: To add to @wOxxOm's helpful comment: If you're not just passing output through, you must wrap the `if` statement in (another) `ForEach-Object` call.

Comment: Oh, i need to check every line for date in begin, and if there no date in home position, insert last seen date until current line. In date placed in home of line, then don't need change this. And export output in file. I imagine how to done it with "if" comandlet, but     where-object    export only one type of lines :(

Comment: `but where-object export only one type of lines` what do you mean by that? Also, Your entire pipeline makes no sense in terms of PowerShell syntax so I don't understand what you want to achieve. That's why it's best to include a sample of the source data and the desired output mockup in the question.

Comment: yes, i piped to the "if" statement. Now I understood.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot use an `if` statement *directly* in a pipeline.**

**Your 2nd use of `foreach` is not a *loop*, but a call to the [`ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** in a *pipeline*.
Regrettably, the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet is aliased to `foreach`, causing confusion with the `foreach` *keyword* (loop construct).

To incorporate an `if` statement (conditional) in a pipeline, you have two options, depending on your needs:

- If the `if` statement only performs *filtering* of the input while - selectively - *passing it through*, use the conditional in the script block of a `Where-Object` call (aliases: `where`, `?`)
- If the `if` statement also produces *custom output*, place it inside the script block of a `ForEach-Object` call (aliases: `foreach`, `%`).

**Simplified examples**:

```
# !! These BREAK - you cannot use `if` directly in a pipeline.
'line 1', 'line 2' | if ($_ -match '1') { $_ }       # filtering only
'line 1', 'line 2' | if ($_ -match '1') { $_ + '!' } # filtering + custom output
```

Filtering-only solution, using `Where-Object`:

```
$ 'line 1', 'line 2' | Where-Object { $_ -match '1' }
line 1
```

Filtering + custom-output solution, using `ForEach-Object`:

```
$ 'line 1', 'line 2' | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match '1') { $_ + '!' } }
line 1!
```

---

**As for your code**:

From what I can tell (including based on later comments), this *may* be what you *meant* to do:

```
Get-Content "OmConv79_2.txt" -TotalCount 100 |
  ForEach-Object { # process each line, represented as $_
    if ($_ -match '^(.*)\t(.+)\t?(.*)?') {
      # Is the first tab-separated field a date + time?
      if ($Matches[1] -match '^\d\d.\d\d.\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\d') {
        $Matches[0] # Output the first 3 tab-separated fields.
      } else {
        # Output line with default date prepended
      }
    }
  }
```

- Note the use of a single pipeline, with a single `ForEach-Object` call to process each input line.
- `-eq` had to be replaced with `-match` to match the `^\d...` regex.
- The regexes are *single-quoted*, so that PowerShell's string interpolation doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it.